# Confusion with some theorems leading to the canonical decomposition of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, modules

Let $\Bbb K$ be a field and $R = \Bbb K[X]$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb K$. Let $\cal L_{\Bbb K}$$(V)$ denote, for a finite dimensional $\Bbb K$-vector space $V$, the set of all $\Bbb K$-linear operators on $V$.

Let $V$ and $\phi \in$$\cal L_{\Bbb K}$$(V)$ be fixed. $R$ acts on $V$ via $P(X) \star v = (P(\phi))(v)$ and we have that $(V, +, \star) =: V_{\phi}$ is an $R$-module. I will denote the annihilator of something in $R$ by $(0: \text{something})_R$. We have that $V_{\phi}$ is a finitely generated torsion $R$-module (in particular, $(0:V_{\phi})_R = Rm_{\phi}(X)$ where $m_{\phi}(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\phi$). Consequently, since $R$ is a PID, there are $q_1(X),...,q_s(X) \in R$, non-constant polynomials, such that $q_1(X) \mid q_2(X) \mid \cdots \mid q_s(X)$, and $V_{\phi} \cong \prod_{i=1}^s R/Rq_i(X)$.

As a consequence, there are $R$-submodules $V_1,...,V_s$ of $V_{\phi}$, such that $V_{\phi} = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_s$ and each $V_i \cong R/Rq_i(X)$. Thus, each $V_i$ is a cyclic $R$-submodule of $V_{\phi}$ and $(0: V_i)_R = Rq_i(X)$.

For $i$, $V_i$ is cyclic and we can write $V_i = R \star v_i$ for some $v_i \in V_i$. Hence, given $v \in V$, there are $b_0,...,b_t \in \Bbb K$ such that $v = b_0 v_i + b_1 \phi(v_i) + \ldots + b_t \phi^t(v_i)$. This shows that $\{v_i,\phi(v_i),\ldots\}$ is a generator of $V_i$.

Now we have the following fact: $W \subset V$ is an $R$-submodule of $V_{\phi}$ iff $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$ and $\phi(W) \subset W$. Hence, if $W$ is an $R$-submodule of $V_{\phi}$, then the restriction $\phi_W$ of $\phi$ on $W$ is a linear operator on $W$ and we have that $(0: W)_R = Rm_{\phi_{W}}(X)$.

Applying this to the above situation, we find that $Rm_{\phi_{V_i}}(X) = Rq_i(X)$ and so $q_i(X)$ and $m_{\phi_{V_i}}(X)$ are associated, hence they have the same degree (say $t_i$). Now $m_{\phi}(\phi) = 0_{L_{\Bbb K}(V)}\implies \{v_i,\phi(v_i),...,\phi^{t_i - 1}(v_i)\}$ is a generator of $V_i$, and it is a free set since $Rm_{\phi_{V_i}}(X) = (0:V_i)_R$.

This gives (more than) a proof of the following theorem:

> There are $R$-submodules $V_1,...,V_s$ of $V_{\phi}$ and there are non-constant polynomials $q_1,...,q_s(X) \in R$, such that $V_{\phi} = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_s$, and for all $i$, $q_i(X) \mid q_{i+1}(X)$, $(0:V_i)_R = Rq_i(X)$ and $\dim_{\Bbb K}(V_i) = \deg(q_i(X))$.

Now the issue is that from where I am reading, the author does not mention the minimal polynomial at all in the proof. In particular, he does not use it to prove the last fact in the theorem. Next, he gives the following theorem:

> Let $W$ be an $R$-submodule of $V_{\phi}$. Then, $W$ is a cyclic $R$-submodule of $V_{\phi}$ iff there exists a basis $B'$ of $V$ over $\Bbb K$, such that $M(\phi_W, B') = C(m_{\phi_W}(X))$ (where $C(P(X))$ denotes the Frobenius companion matrix of a monic polynomial).

The given proof is awful and, again, does not make use of the discussion in paragraphs $5$ and $6$ of this post, which can make the proof a piece of cake because there, we only made use of the fact that $V_i$ is cyclic and $(0: V_i)_R = m_{\phi_{V_i}}(X)$, and the latter is true of any $R$-submodule of $V_{\phi}$. After that, the author gives the remark:

> We deduce that if $W$ is a cyclic $R$-submodule of $V_{\phi}$, then $\dim_{\Bbb K}(W) = \deg(m_{\phi_W}(X))$.

This gave me a shock because I am not sure anymore whether my reasoning is correct, for had it been so, things would become much less complicated.

What I mean is that the latter fact (given by the remark) can be demonstrated in an independent manner of the preceding theorems (as I think I did correctly in paragraphs $5$ and $6$ of this post) and it can be then used to prove the above two theorems in a neat fashion.

Is my reasoning correct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you did looks correct.

My guess is that the author did not want to make any references to the "Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Modules over a PID" since you can develop the rational canonical form independently. That is what you used, and yes it trivializes the arguments because the rational canonical form is just a special case of it.